# How to make sitemap template accessible from root?

Tags: templates

I have created a template that outputs my XML Sitemap dynamically (via Channel entry loop). Currently, it's in `commmon/sitemap.xml`. How do I tell EE that whenever `http://somedomain.com/sitemap.xml` is accessed, it should output `commmon/sitemap.xml`?

Comment: While trying to solve the same problem, I did some research and found it was unnecessary, at least with respect to [Google support](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2008/02/cross-submissions-via-robotstxt-on.html). Not only is it okay to put a sitemap in a subdomain, you can put it at an entirely different URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure your index.php rewrite happens **after** the rewrite to the template group.

```
RewriteCond $1 ^(sitemap_index\.xml|sitemap\.xml|product-feed\.xml) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /common/$1 [L]
...
RewriteCond $1 !^(images|themes|robots\.txt|index\.php|admin\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

For certain builds with strict 404's and using Structure, I've had to create a page in Structure to keep it happy, but otherwise it should rewrite fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [resource router](https://github.com/rsanchez/resource_router) by Sanchez. I expect you could do something similar with EE template routes too.

Alternatively, you could look at modifying your htaccess rules.

Comment: I'm not sure how resource router can help as it seems to require the template group name. What's the template group name of root? I've tried this rewrite rule: `RewriteRule ^/?sitemap\.xml$ /common/sitemap.xml [L]`, but it doesn't work because I think it expects "/common/sitemap.xml" to be a "real" file.

Comment: Remove the 2nd  `.xml` part from your htacess.

Comment: Why? If I go to `http://domain.com/common/sitemap.xml`, I get to the template. However, if I go to `http://domain.com/common/sitemap/`, I get nothing.